# Postgresql custom type reflection

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

In PostgreSQL 9.5.3 I've created a custom type and then that type is the parameter to a stored procedure.  I'm then doing an UPDATE statement using the properties of that type, so I end up with something like:

```sql
UPDATE someTable SET 
    col1 = col1 + myTypeParam.col1,
    col2 = col2 + myTypeParam.col2,
    ...
    col10 = col10 +myTypeParam.col10 
WHERE someConditionHere
```

I don't want to hardcode all those columns though.  Is there a way to use reflection or something like that instead of listing each piece explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

You could compose a statement string using the system catalogs and use `EXECUTE` to execute it as dynamic SQL.